# How to call an Alert with Activity Indicator on Xamarim?

Tags: c#, xamarin, activity-indicator

I have a code where, after a button click, i start running an Activity Indicator, then after some task, i stop it.

I would like to call a Display Alert function after it. Heres my code:

```
private void BtnConect_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activityIndicatorLogin.IsRunning = true;
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => TEST());
}

protected void TEST()
{
    activityIndicatorLogin.IsRunning = false;
    DisplayAlert("tiitle test", "messsage test", "close");
}
```

The Activity Indicator runs correctly, it starts and stops as I want. But the alert isnt called! It doesnt throw any excpetions or something, but the alert pop-up doesnt appear!

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping your alert with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
 DisplayAlert("tiitle test", "messsage test", "close");
});  Since you are calling from the non UI thread.

Comment: Still doesnt work. It keep doing as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Has to be called from uithread + await the display alert or it might not appear.
(If this onclicked is fired from a control in your ui, dont worry about the the thread its running on)

```
private async void BtnConect_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activityIndicatorLogin.IsRunning = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await TEST();
}

protected async Task TEST()
{
    activityIndicatorLogin.IsRunning = false;
    await DisplayAlert("tiitle test", "messsage test", "close");
}
```